# How to pass Non-essential Built-in object as parameter in django-rq enqueue

Tags: python, django, python-rq, django-rq

Update: I found that I could not even pass a class in the `enqueue`, is this possible to do this?

---

I want to pass a `item` object (a model in Django) as the parameter in `queue.enqueue(grabber.parse_body, item)`, but the `rqworker` will raise this Exception (once I tried to pass the item as parameter in spite of whether I use it):

> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/rq/job.py", line 53, in
>   unpickle
>       raise UnpickleError('Could not unpickle.', pickled_string, e) rq.exceptions.UnpickleError: ('Could not unpickle.',
>   ImproperlyConfigured('Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings
>   are not configured. You must either define the environment variable
>   DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing
>   settings.',))

Seems that `parse_body` don't know what the `item` is?

**I know I could just pass the items's id as parameter, and then deal with id in `parse_body`, but is this possible to use `item` directly in `parse_body`?**

---

My main code:
(`enqueue.py` and `grabber.py` are independent script, not in the Django apps.)

enqueue.py

```
import os
import grabber
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "website.settings.development")

queue = django_rq.get_queue('default')
need_to_parse = Post.objects.all()
    for item in need_to_parse:
        queue.enqueue(grabber.parse_body, item)
```

grabber.py

```
def parse_body(item):
    print(item)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that RQ's default pickler is cPickle which does not know how to serialize django model instances. A simpler approach would be to use model_to_dict and pass a pickable object to your queue.

```
from django.models import model_to_dict
my_dict = model_to_dict(my_instance,fields=[],exclude=[])
```

If you are intent on using django model instances in your queue, you can create your own Job class that uses a PickleSerializer first and then set your Queue.job to your new CustomJob(Job). https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/sessions/#bundled-serializers

Comment: Updated link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#bundled-serializers

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message because I started rqworker with the command

> $ rqworker

I fixed this by typing

> $ python manage.py rqworker